# In python with pywin32, win32job, the CreateJobObject function, how do I pass NULL for the name parameter?

Tags: python, window, pywin32

I'm trying to use the win32job API that is part of the PyWin32 package.  I want to do this:

```
win32job.CreateJobObject(None, NULL)
```

I want to pass NULL as the second parameter as documented here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682409(v=vs.85).aspx

> If lpName is NULL, the job is created without a name.

How do I pass in NULL?

Here's what I hoped would work, but doesn't:

```
win32job.CreateJobObject(None, None)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: None is not a valid string in this context
```

---

(Side question... if anyone knows how to view JobObjects associated with a process in Windows, that would be helpful.)

Comment: In case it helps, I downloaded the pywin32 source code.  It seems to use swig: 

````// @pyswig |CreateJobObject|Creates or opens a job object.
PyHANDLE CreateJobObject(
  SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *lpJobAttributes, // @pyparm <o PySECURITY_ATTRIBUTES>|jobAttributes||
  WCHAR *lpName); // @pyparm unicode|name||````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `win32job.CreateJobObject(None, "")`. Although it isn't specified on [[MS.Docs]: CreateJobObjectA function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createjobobjecta), the empty string acts just like *NULL*.

According to the link above:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the job object. The handle has the **JOB_OBJECT_ALL_ACCESS** access right. If the object existed before the function call, the function returns a handle to the existing job object and [GetLastError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/d852e148-985c-416f-a5a7-27b6914b45d4) returns **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS**.

I wrote a small *C* program for demonstrating purposes:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define EMPTY_TEXT ""
#define DUMMY0_TEXT "dummy0"
#define DUMMY1_TEXT "dummy1"

#define DIM 12

int main() {
    char* names[DIM] = { NULL, NULL, EMPTY_TEXT, EMPTY_TEXT, DUMMY0_TEXT,
                         DUMMY0_TEXT, EMPTY_TEXT, DUMMY0_TEXT, DUMMY1_TEXT,
                         NULL, DUMMY0_TEXT, DUMMY1_TEXT };
    HANDLE jobs[DIM] = { NULL };
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        jobs[i] = CreateJobObjectA(NULL, names[i]);
        printf("%02d [%6s] CreateJobObject: %08X - GetLastError: %d\n", i, names[i], (long)jobs[i], GetLastError());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < DIM; i++)
        CloseHandle(jobs[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Output** (built and ran with *VStudio 2015 Community Edition*):

> ```bat
> 00 [(null)] CreateJobObject: 000000D8 - GetLastError: 0
> 01 [(null)] CreateJobObject: 000000E0 - GetLastError: 0
> 02 [      ] CreateJobObject: 00000088 - GetLastError: 0
> 03 [      ] CreateJobObject: 000000F0 - GetLastError: 0
> 04 [dummy0] CreateJobObject: 000000F4 - GetLastError: 0
> 05 [dummy0] CreateJobObject: 000000F8 - GetLastError: 183
> 06 [      ] CreateJobObject: 000000E8 - GetLastError: 0
> 07 [dummy0] CreateJobObject: 000000FC - GetLastError: 183
> 08 [dummy1] CreateJobObject: 00000100 - GetLastError: 0
> 09 [(null)] CreateJobObject: 000000DC - GetLastError: 0
> 10 [dummy0] CreateJobObject: 000000E4 - GetLastError: 183
> 11 [dummy1] CreateJobObject: 00000104 - GetLastError: 183
> ```

You can see that for *"dummy0"* and *"dummy"*, every time (excepting the 1<sup>st</sup>) when creating a new object, the function does return a new *HANDLE*, but fails (*GetLastError* returns *183* (which is *ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS*)). This doesn't happen for *NULL* **and** the empty string names (from here I understand that a new object is created with every call instead of incrementing an existing object's reference).

*Python* "translation" (*code.py*):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import win32job
import win32api

DUMMY0 = "dummy00"
DUMMY1 = "dummy11"

JOB_NAMES = ["", "", DUMMY0, DUMMY0, "", DUMMY1, DUMMY0, "", DUMMY1]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handles = list()
    for i, name in enumerate(JOB_NAMES):
        h = win32job.CreateJobObject(None, name)
        print("{} [{:10}] {} - GetLastError: {}".format(i, name, h, win32api.GetLastError()))
        handles.append(h)

    for h in handles:
        win32api.CloseHandle(h)
```

**Output** (same result as in *C*'s case - which is natural since *Python* functions only wrap the lower level *C* ones):

> ```bat
> (py35x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q046800142>"c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py35x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> 0 [          ] <PyHANDLE:300> - GetLastError: 0
> 1 [          ] <PyHANDLE:308> - GetLastError: 0
> 2 [dummy00   ] <PyHANDLE:580> - GetLastError: 0
> 3 [dummy00   ] <PyHANDLE:584> - GetLastError: 183
> 4 [          ] <PyHANDLE:588> - GetLastError: 0
> 5 [dummy11   ] <PyHANDLE:592> - GetLastError: 0
> 6 [dummy00   ] <PyHANDLE:596> - GetLastError: 183
> 7 [          ] <PyHANDLE:600> - GetLastError: 0
> 8 [dummy11   ] <PyHANDLE:604> - GetLastError: 183
> ```

Regarding the "side" question: unfortunately, I'm not familiar with that topic.